# Jsonnet: How to do String Formatting + String Joining together?

Tags: json, string, format, jsonnet

I want to make this expression more readable so that it's easier to add new variables if needed, so I tried writing something like this:

```
std.format('{%s}',
        std.join(', ', [
        std.format('"account": "%s"', dev_account_id),
        std.format('"service": "%s"', business_service),
        std.format('"dir": "%s"', kms_module_dir)
        ])
      )
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
app_metaflow/shore/main.pipeline.jsonnet:(58:19)-(72:8)\tobject <anonymous>\n\tDuring manifestation\t\n"
RUNTIME ERROR: Missing argument: vals
    /mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/d-platform_fusmltrn-app_metaflow/shore/main.pipeline.jsonnet:63:9-35    thunk from <thunk from <thunk from <object <anonymous>>>>
    /mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/d-platform_fusmltrn-app_metaflow/shore/main.pipeline.jsonnet:(59:9)-(71:11) thunk from <object <anonymous>>
    <std>:769:20-24 thunk from <function <anonymous>>
    <std>:32:25-26  thunk from <function <anonymous>>
    <std>:32:16-27  function <anonymous>
    <std>:769:8-25  function <anonymous>
```

I basically want to create a string equivalent of this, but more readable

```
std.format('{"account": "%s", "service": "%s", "dir": "%s"}', [dev_account_id, business_service, kms_module_dir])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, as your example did work for me (using `jsonnet` `v0.19.1`), nevertheless it *looks* like your building a JSON string, thus it may be worth using native function(s) to do so.

Below example shows your implementation, together with a JSON- native approach:

### src: foo.jsonnet

```js
local dev_account_id = 'someId';
local business_service = 'someService';
local kms_module_dir = 'someDir';
[
  // Manual string formatting
  std.format(
    '{%s}',
    std.join(', ', [
      std.format('"account": "%s"', dev_account_id),
      std.format('"service": "%s"', business_service),
      std.format('"dir": "%s"', kms_module_dir),
    ])
  ),
  // Looks like JSON, let's use native function
  std.manifestJsonMinified({
    account: dev_account_id,
    service: business_service,
    dir: kms_module_dir,
  }),
]
```

### output

```shell
$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet
[
   "{\"account\": \"someId\", \"service\": \"someService\", \"dir\": \"someDir\"}",
   "{\"account\":\"someId\",\"dir\":\"someDir\",\"service\":\"someService\"}"
]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
```
time="2023-03-09T17:57:22Z" level=error msg="Renderer.Render returned an error RUNTIME ERROR: Field does not exist: manifestJsonMinified\n\t/mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/d-platform_fusmltrn-app_metaflow/shore/main.pipeline.jsonnet:59:19-43\tobject <anonymous>\n\tDuring manifestation\t\n"
RUNTIME ERROR: Field does not exist: manifestJsonMinified
 /mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/d-platform_fusmltrn-app_metaflow/shore/main.pipeline.jsonnet:59:19-43 object <anonymous>
 During manifestation 
```

Comment: most likely an outdated `jsonnet` version, note the version I added to my reply above

Comment: else, you can just use `std.manifestJson()` instead, which produces a more whitespaced output (tho still correct JSON of course)

Comment: Oh okay thanks -I'll give that a try too, thanks! Yeah I don't think I can control for the jsonnet version but I can ask our DevOps team.